# Find why a specific package is installed in a big chain of dnf dependencies

Tags: yum, dnf

I'm trying to do a 'dnf update' and getting a bunch of errors like:

```
 Problem 2: cannot install both libinput-1.16.3-2.el8.x86_64 and libinput-1.16.3-1.el8.x86_64
  - package libinput-devel-1.16.3-1.el8.x86_64 requires libinput(x86-64) = 1.16.3-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libinput-1.16.3-1.el8.x86_64
  - problem with installed package libinput-devel-1.16.3-1.el8.x86_64
```

My assumption is that something is requiring specifically the old version and thus dnf is refusing to update it. Is there a way for me to find exactly what requires it?

Everything I find online answers the reverse question: Given a package, what are its dependencies. I'm asking "given a dependency, find what package had it required."

Answer (score 2):

To find out what installed package(s) require a given package, use

```
dnf repoquery --installed --whatrequires package
```

For example,

```
dnf repoquery --installed --whatrequires libinput
```

Given the output in your question, it appears that the package holding back `libinput` is `libinput-devel` itself!